# ntfs-3g executable permission on Windows in dual-boot environment

Tags: windows, dual-boot, ntfs-3g

I am using an NTFS partition to share data between my Manjaro Linux and Windows 10 installations. Basic mounting with `ntfs-3g` works perfectly, and I have been able to establish user [permission mapping](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/trusty/man8/ntfs-3g.usermap.8.html).

The Linux file system creates files with UNIX permissions `0644` by default. In particular, this means that any new file is **not** executable (`chmod +x`) by default. This is fine and perfectly clear to me.

Problem: When booting into Windows 10 and downloading any generic `setup.exe` from the Internet, that file is not executable on Windows either, despite being "created" there! I get error messages that roughly translate to (my installtion is in German) *Unable to open the file. Either it is on an invalid path or you do not have the permissions necessary to execute the desired action*.

The current solution is to shut down, boot into Linux, execute `chmod +x /shareddisc/path/to/downloaded/file`, then boot into Windows again. Doing so **does fix** the problem.

Why does this happen, and how can I have Windows create these files as executable in the first place? Rebooting every time I download a setup is really painful.

System Information

1. Manjaro Linux

   - Version 19.0.2 Kyria
   - Kernel 5.5.16
   - fstab mount options: `UUID=5327DD064405A05B /media/shareos    ntfs    defaults,noatime,permissions,rw,exec 0 0`
2. Windows

   - Windows 10 with all updates as of 2020-04-19
   - Shared drive mounted as `D:\`
3. ntfs-3g

   - version `ntfs-3g 2017.3.23 external FUSE 29`

Usermapping file:

```
# Generated by ntfsusermap for Linux, v 1.2.0
:1001:S-1-5-21-2651015022-247621189-3734135628-513
1000:1000:S-1-5-21-2651015022-247621189-3734135628-1001
```

Thanks!

Comment: Normal ntfs partition on the same disk or is it a network share or somtheing similar?

Comment: Struggling with the same. Here are some windows cmds that might troubleshoot your situation but not a real solution. 

# take ownership and grant permissions
# replace directory and user with you own
takeown /F D:\Users\krist
takeown /F D:\Users\krist /r /d y
icacls D:\Users\krist /grant WINBLOWZ\Kristof:F
icacls D:\Users\krist /grant WINBLOWZ\Kristof:F /t

# resetting windows permissions
icacls D:\Users\krist /reset /t /c /l